# Kinect (Microsoft Sdk) Skeleton (recorded) Data from pixel to 3d real world coordinates

Tags: matlab, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have a dataset of partial joints (right elbow, shoulder and wrist) taken from a fellow who acquired this data with OpenNi.
The joints are in pixel as regarding to x and y, while z is in mm. I have to convert them to real world space to match them with data acquired by me (using Microsoft Sdk) for a gesture recognition application. I'm working in Matlab.

Searching on web and papers, I found that a floor reference is necessary for the conversion but I don't have any, so how could this conversion be done, possibly in matlab, and which candidate should I pick ? (maybe height of kinect from the floor?)

Comment: What are you using to learn the gestures?

Comment: Why do you need both datasets to be in the same worldspace?

Comment: I'm using DTW for recognition i need that the vectors are the same type of data to  match them(because i compute euclidean distance so i need to be the same magnitude).I consider gestures like a time series of 3d vectors(so a 3*3 matrix , xyz coordinates for shoulder,elbow ans wrist)

Comment: Any answer please . I'm stuck in

Comment: In our project we considered 'hip' as a reference point.It was sufficient in our case.Not exactly sure whether it'll work for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not-so-awesome solution:

1. Plot the 3D points you have of both data sets
2. Look for a pose where the arm and the forearm seems to be making a similar pose (as L-shaped as possible).
3. Use this to compute the transformation.